# Laravel how to groupBy nested relation

Tags: laravel

I have 4 models:
User: The user model

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{  
    public function affectation()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Affectation::class);
    }
}
```

Role: the role model

```
class Role extends Model
{

    public function operations()
        {
            return $this->hasMany(Operation::class);
        }
    
        public function affectation()
        {
            return $this->hasMany(Affectation::class);
        }
    }
```

Project: the project model

```
class Project extends Model
{
public function affectation()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Affectation::class);
    }
}
```

Affectation: an affectation of a user with a role to a project ( a user can have more than a role in the same project)

```
class Affectation extends Model
{
    public function project()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Project::class);
    }
    public function role()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Role::class);
    }
    public function agent()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'user_id');
    }
}
```

I want to find the user roles in a specific project, I tried ( for project with id 1):

```
return  User::whereHas('affectation', function (Builder $query) {
    $query->where('project_id', '=', 1);
})->with('affectation.role')->get();
```

The result:

```
[
    {
        "id": 4,
        "name": "Doe"
        "affectation": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "role_id": 1,
                "user_id": 4,
                "project_id": 1
                "role": {
                    "id": 1,
                    "name": "Dev"
                }
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "role_id": 2,
                "user_id": 4,
                "project_id": 1
                "role": {
                    "id": 2,
                    "name": "Scrum Master"
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 5,
        "name": "Jhon"
        "affectation": [
            {
                "id": 3,
                "role_id": 1,
                "user_id": 5,
                "project_id": 1
                "role": {
                    "id": 1,
                    "name": "DEV"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

But I want to achieve like this:

```
[
   {
      "id":1,
      "project_name":"Microsoft",
      "users":[
         {
            "id":"1",
            "name":"Doe",
            "role":[
               {
                  "id":"1",
                  "name":"DEV"
               },
               {
                  "id":"2",
                  "name":"SCRUM MASTER"
               }
            ]
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try add this in the Project Model:

```
/**
 * Get all of the user for the project.
 */
public function users()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough(User::class, Affectation::class);
}
```

And add this in User model:

```
public function roles()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough(Role::class, Affectation::class);
}
```

The first argument passed to the hasManyThrough method is the name of the final model we wish to access, while the second argument is the name of the intermediate model.
For more information, see the official documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through

And your final query should be as follows:

```
return Project::where('id', '=', 1)->with('users.roles')->get();
```

Comment: Unfortunately the hasManyThrough doesn't work because the User doesn't have a foreign key for Affectation